# Trouble running program with Python27-Newbie

Tags: python, windows, directory

okay, im a new guy at all this, just randomly picked it up with my neighbor and we are both stuck at this. We have been following this tutorial([here](http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/python/#intro)) and have made it to 6.6 in the tutorial. I have searched the forums looking for a way to get passed my problem but all the of questions people have are too complex for me as of right now. I am running windows 8.1 on my laptop, i have python27. So here we go i put in,

```
>>> cd c:\\py
```

and i get

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
cd c:\\py
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Then i searched around and found a thread saying to use os.chdir so i gave that a shot and got;

```
>>> os.chdir("c:\\py")
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\py'
>>>
```

So my guess is that it worked? so then i go ahead and try to run my program like it says to do, so i put in

```
python hello.py
```

and i get this in return

```
>>> python hello.py
File "<stdin>", line 1
python hello.py
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm literally stuck, i have no clue what to do now. If someone can help me through this i will love you long time.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Python shell differs from system shell (cmd.exe). You try to run `python script.py` in Python interpreter instead of `cmd.exe`.

Open `cmd.exe` and type in `python script.py` to solve this. It'll run fine if it doesn't contain any errors. `cd c:\\` doesn't work due to the same reason.

First `quit()` or `exit()` the Python interpreter (type one of them right in it) then type the commands you want to execute (such as `cd`) into terminal.

If you want to run `code.py` in Python interpreter, you can `os.chdir("...")` to the directory where your script resides and type `import code`. That may not work if your script contains

```
if __name__=="__main__":
```

All in all, Python interpreter is for running Python code right in it and command prompt (terminal, cmd.exe) is for running other non-GUI programs and much more.

Comment: so, going cmd and typing python and making my cmd python is basically a live sketchpad to put in codes and see if it works? and if they do i put them into a file and run the file just through the cmd with python in front?

Comment: @akaphobia, you're right. Python interpreter is like IDLE without GUI.

Comment: @akaphobia, you can just run `script.py`, which will run using the .py file type association.

Answer (score 1):

You are in the python interpreter which is an interactive shell.  You can consider it "scratch paper" to test out or try different things.

To run your script : 
  quit()
  in the command prompt run python.exe hello.py ( on windows.. on *nix just python)

Comment: okay so i got it to open in the cmd, but why wont it open when i have the cmd in python?

Comment: cmd isn't a recognized function call or object in python.  you would need to do something like os.system('cmd .. ') or something of that nature.  The interpreter can only recognize python.

Comment: i ment i got it to open in the command prompt but i was asking why it wouldnt open when i had the command prompt set to python.

Comment: Right, I understand :) So, the command prompt (when you type cmd and the black window pops up) is a command line shell that lets you interact with the operating system via command line .. commands.  When you type python, that opens up a new program.  The same as opening up the command prompt, its a completely different program, just in the same window.  It is no longer the dos shell, so none of those commands work anymore, only python. Does that make it a bit clearer?